# Why doesn't my simple filename extension check work?

Tags: php

```
// What's my mime?
$_mime = 'text/plain';
if ($_file[strlen($_file)-1] == 'j') { $_mime = 'text/javascript'; }
else { $_mime = 'text/css'; }
```

I really don't understand why the above does not work, my server will response with two input types either .min.js or .min.css

It should take the last character, step back one, which should either be `j` or `s`.

The response is always text/css regardless. Of course strict mime restriction then breaks my entire website.

Comment: This has nothing to do with mime types. It's checking the file name.

Comment: Why not just `$_mime = mime_content_type($_file);`?

Comment: @BrandonHorsley this was the original line of code I replaced because it failed to detect any mime types correctly. A Symfony Framework issue I believe. Always returned text/plain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're off by one, a common error.

Let's say your filename is `script.js`.

The length is 9, but since the count in an array starts from 0, the `j` is the 7th letter, and the `s` the 8th.

```
string.js
^       ^
0       8
```

So just do `if ($_file[strlen($_file)-2] == 'j')`

```js
$file = 'script.js';

console.log('File name length:', $file.length);
console.log('First letter:', $file[0]);
console.log('Last letter:', $file[$file.length - 1]);
console.log('The letter you want:', $file[$file.length - 2]);
```

Also, I'm assuming `$_file` is a string with the name of your file.

**Anyway, I hope you're aware you aren't doing a mime-type check, but just checking the file extension - this doesn't provide any security to you, and you cannot be sure about the mime-type of the file. You need to trust the source of the file.** So do not use this way to determine the mime-type if the file is uploaded to your server by a third party.

Comment: This has resolved the issue. I know there are better ways to detect mime type, unfortunately, the framework (symfony) has a broken mime-type check which always returns text/plain. - I needed a light & quick solution which resolved it asap for now.

Comment: @JordanDyckes see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php which was mentioned by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642915/why-doesnt-my-simple-mime-type-check-work#comment64669364_38642915)

Comment: @JordanDyckes glad it helped. Please accept the answer then :)

Comment: @rpadovani trying to figure out how to accept it, can't see any obvious buttons or links? :) turns out I just have to click the tick symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are just checking the file extension, in that case you could try a simple function like this to get the extension.

```
function filename($file){
    return substr($file,0,strrpos($file,'.'));
}
function extension($file){
    return strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,'.'),1));
}
```

Note that this function is not bullet proof but in a simple scenario such as your it would work.